# Homological class of the fiber in the total space of the one circle bundle

Tags: fibre-bundles

It is a well known fact that (isomorphism classes of) princial $\mathbb{S
}^1$-bundles over a base space $B$ are classified by $B$'s second integral cohomology, $H^2(B;\mathbb{Z}$), by the Euler class. In trivial case, null Euler class, we have that the fiber $\mathbb{S}^1$ represent one non trivial real homological class in $B\times \mathbb{S}^1$.

Question:

In the non trivial case (non zero Euler class), is the fiber homologous to zero  in the total space (real homology)?

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.  For example, for circle bundles over $S^2$, Euler class 2 corresponds to the circle bundle with total space $\mathbb R P^3$ with fiber representing the generator of $1$-dimensional homology of the total space.

Comment: Thanks very much. I conclude that the fiber is zero in the $\mathbb{R}$ cohomology if, and only if, the Euler characteristic represents a torsion element (https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.14190).